# How to detect if obj is being added or edited inside ModelForm.clean?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-validation

I want to validate user submitted data differently whether the user is adding a new object or changing an existing one. There isn't an attribute of the model other than the id that I could check on the db if the object already exist (if it exist on the db, it's being added). 
In other methods, like save_model, a add parameter is passed, so you can check it, but in modelform.clean there is no such parameter. How to do that verification inside modelform.clean?

```
MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        if add :
            validation_A()
        else:
            validantion_B()
```

Comment: You can check if `self.instance.id is None`, since new objects have up to that point no `id` assigned by the database.

Comment: But that being said, I find it rather weird that an edit/create has different validations, since typically the two are more or less symmetric.

Comment: you can pas variable inside your init method and check with that variable...

Comment: Please give us your main scenario and your models, forms, and views....I help !

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An object that does not exists at the database level has an `id` (well perhaps it is better to use `pk`) that is `None` (since the `id` is determined upon an insert in the database, Django does not assign that id).

So we can check if the `self.instance.pk is None`:

```
MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        if self.instance.pk is None:  # add
            validation_A()
        else:                         # edit
            validantion_B()
```

Of course the above method can be "spoofed" in the sense that before you pass the object in the creation, you can set the `id` to `None`, but the `Model.save(..)` object uses this fact as well to decide wether to perform an `INSERT INTO`, or an `UPDATE`.

Comment: I know this is old, but my scenario where this made sense is that I have an object that needs validation for a unique value only once, as that field cannot be updated after the fact - it becomes a hidden field on the update form. If I don't differentiate, then the validation triggers on the hidden field and blocks the update.

Answer (score 1):

The solution with checking `self.instance.pk` or `self.instance.id` won't work if the primary key is non-auto field. In this case, the value will be pre-populated by Django and would always be `not None`.

Better solution would be checking the model instance [state](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model._state):

```py
if self.instance._state.adding:  # add
    validation_A()
else:                            # edit
    validation_B()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.